# How to display local video in a PhoneGap app?

Tags: ipad, video, cordova

How can I display a video in a PhoneGap app for iPad ?

I can't find any reference.

Answer (score 4):

In the Ipad's case you should use the html 5 video tag, and an example of its use is the following:

```
<video controls="controls" autoplay="autoplay">
   <source src="yourVideo.mp4" type="video/mp4" />
   <source src="yourVideo.webm" type="video/webm" />
   <source src="yourVideo.ogv" type="video/ogg" />
</video>
```

I used it only with the mp4 extension, and my video was encoding  with h264 codec for video and AAC codec for audio codec.

In the Android's, I used a Phonegap plugin from github called web Intent (https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap-plugins/tree/master/Android/WebIntent) a example of usage is:

```
window.plugins.webintent.startActivity({
    action: WebIntent.ACTION_VIEW,
    url: 'http"//yourVideo.mp4'},
    function() {console.log('Is wirking :D!');},
    function() {console.log('Failed to open the URL :( !!');}
 );
```

resources:

http://diveintohtml5.info/ (html5/ipad/iphone)

http://www.808.dk/?code-html-5-video (html5/ipad/iphone)

http://smus.com/android-phonegap-plugins (Android)

Answer (score 2):

A quick search of the [PhoneGap API](http://docs.phonegap.com/index.html) does not show any way to do so. However, [a quick Google Search](http://www.google.com/#hl=en&sugexp=ldymls&xhr=t&q=phonegap+video+playback&cp=14&pf=p&sclient=psy&safe=active&aq=0&aqi=&aql=&oq=phonegap+video+playback&pbx=1&fp=3f8c1f6954acb9e1) returns [this](http://groups.google.com/group/phonegap/msg/8c5a88ad6434b783), which suggests simply using the HTML video tag.

Comment: I've tried but it crashes with SIGABRT <body onload="onBodyLoad()">
 <video src="Cars2.m4v" >
  your browser does not support the video tag
 </video>
  </body>

Comment: What does your debugger say? Have you checked your video path? Encoding format?

Comment: The Android 2.1/2.2 WebView does not support the <video> tag

Comment: @MattRogish - the you'd be out of luck.

Comment: It should work fine on iPad, though. Android is the problem child

Answer (score 1):

There is a [plugin](http://simonmacdonald.blogspot.com/2011/11/video-player-plugin-for-phonegap.html), which allows playing video with phonegap/cordova on Android. It helped a lot in my case. About IOS + Phonegap - it supports video tag (unlike Android + phonegap).