# phonegap function not working in webview

Tags: android, cordova, webview

I am trying to build a simple app using webview but unable to get phonegap functions working when I use the webview class. If I use "super" then the phonegap function works fine. Excuse my odd vocabulary.

///////////////// JAVA //////////////////////////

```
public class MainStart extends DroidGap {

HTML5WebView mWebView;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    CookieSyncManager.createInstance(this);
    CookieSyncManager.getInstance().sync();

    mWebView = new HTML5WebView(this);
    mWebView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    mWebView.addJavascriptInterface(new JavaScriptInterface(this), "MyAndroid");
    mWebView.getSettings().setPluginsEnabled(true);

    mWebView.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/www/index.html"); // phonegap function does not work 

    super.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/www/index.html");    // phonegap function works here

    }

}
```

///////////////// JAVASCRIPT //////////////////////////

```
 function onDeviceReady(){

      navigator.notification.alert("PhoneGap is working");

 }
```

Comment: super's type is DroidGap. mWebView's is not

Comment: Thank you for the insight. I have alot to learn.

Answer (score 0):

the WebView that PhoneGap sets up include a multitude of features which you are not even referencing in your own WebView - like the Javascript bridge - without it there's no way you can call Native code from within your html page!

may I ask why exactly are you trying to re-create your own WebView, instead of just using the standard supplied one?

Comment: I recreated  webview because the standard one does not play videos with the <video> tag and I found this code here [link](http://code.google.com/p/html5webview/source/browse/trunk/HTML5WebViw/src/org/itri/html5webview/TestHTML5WebView.java?r=2) which fixes webview so it will play videos w/ <video>. Is there a way to get the WebView that PhoneGap sets up to inherit the new webview class that I have defined?  Thank you for your input on this situation. I am still very new to mobile dev.

Comment: according to [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4854153/how-to-display-local-video-in-a-phonegap-app) there really is no way, with the video tag; but apparentely there is a [way to get videos to work](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/phonegap/boMH5X2FfN0) with PhoneGap without having to re-create a whole new WebView ;)

Comment: besides, PhoneGap is still open-source which means you can fork your own version from [github](https://github.com/phonegap) and actually change the source code to fit yar needs! Who knows, maybe one day they'll even PULL your changes and we can then all benefit from it :D

Comment: Ok - thanks for clearing that up about the video tag. I've actually been following that groups google link that you posted also and was able to implement it into my app. But then hit another wall, when trying to get the video to play that needs authentication from a login. So far those solutions calls a native android player and I could not get the native android player to get through the authentication and play the video. This is why I've used my own webview which can play the video w/ <video> tag and get through authentication. Thanks for taking the time to help in solving this issue. I'll p

Comment: I'll post up new solutions if I come across them.

Comment: my point exactly - you can change the original WebView from PhoneGap by adding your changes, that way allowing <video> tags with authentication inside your PhoneGap html pages..